# How to connect a client to a server with sockets, using ip adress in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, socketserver

This is probably very simple, but I am having trouble with it.
This is code I am using for the server.
I've searched for this  but I only found different kinds of sockets to the one I am using.

```
server = socket.socket()
server.bind(("localhost", 6969))
server.listen(1)
socket_client, datos_client = server.accept() 

print ("Wainting message...") 
data = socket_client.recv(1000) 
print ("Message:", data)

send1 = bytes("Bye","utf-8")
socket_client.send(send1)   

print ("Closing..." )

socket_client.close() 
server.close()
```

And this is the code for the client:

```
import socket

def main():

    my_socket_client = socket.socket()
    my_socket_client.connect(("localhost", 6969))

    bufsize = 1000

    print("Send message")
    message=input()
    data2 = bytes(mensaje,"utf-8")
    #enviar los datos
    my_socket_client.send(data2)

    data_received= my_socket_client.recv(bufsize)

    print (data_received)
```

Comment: You are using **message** and **mensaje**? `data2` will be sent as nothing

Comment: You need to tell us the problem

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your problem is since you didn't ask a question so i will just show you a client + basic command server that i have built in the same way you built yours you said "I only found different kinds of sockets to the one I am using." so i hope this is what you are looking for

Here is an example of a simple command server:
if you run the server code and then run the client you will be able to type in the client and send to the server. if you type TIME you will get from the server a respons which contains a string that has the date of today and the other commands work in the same way. if you type EXIT it will close the connection and will send from the server the string closing to the client

server:

```
import socket
import random
from datetime import date


server_socket = socket.socket()                           # new socket object
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8820))                     # empty bind (will connect to a real ip later)

server_socket.listen(1)                                   # see if any client is trying to connect

(client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()  # accept the connection
while True: # main server loop
    client_cmd = client_socket.recv(1024)                 # recive user input from client
    # check waht command was entered
    if client_cmd == "TIME":
        client_socket.send(str(date.today()))             # send the date
    elif client_cmd == "NAME":
        client_socket.send("best server ever")            # send this text
    elif client_cmd == "RAND":
        client_socket.send(str(random.randrange(1,11,1))) # send this randomly generated number
    elif client_cmd == "EXIT":
        client_socket.send("closing")
        client_socket.close()                             # close the connection with the client
        server_socket.close()                             # close the server
        break
    else :
        client_socket.send("there was an error in the commend sent")

client_socket.close()                                     # just in case try to close again
server_socket.close()                                     # just in case try to close again
```

client:

```
import socket

client_socket = socket.socket()                    # new socket object
client_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8820))         # connect to the server on port 8820, the ip '127.0.0.1' is special because it will always refer to your own computer

while True:
    try:
        print "please enter a commend"
        print "TIME - request the current time"
        print "NAME - request the name of the server"
        print "RAND - request a random number"
        print "EXIT - request to disconnect the sockets"
        cmd = raw_input("please enter your name") # user input

        client_socket.send(cmd)                   # send the string to the server

        data = client_socket.recv(1024)           # recive server output
        print "the server sent: " + data          # print that data from the server
        print
        if data == "closing":
            break
    except:
        print "closing server"
        break

client_socket.close()                             # close the connection with the server
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo .

edit this line in client from

```
data2 = bytes(mensaje,"utf-8")
```

to

```
data2 = bytes(message,"utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and made a couple of changes:

Server side:

```
import socket

server = socket.socket() 
server.bind(("localhost", 6969))     
server.listen(1)
socket_client, datos_client = server.accept() 
print ("Waiting message...") 
data = socket_client.recv(1000) 
print ("Message:", data )
# Same change made as with client side
send1 = bytes("Bye") #,"utf-8")
socket_client.send(send1) 
print ("Closing..." )    
socket_client.close() 
server.close()
```

Client side:

```
import socket

my_socket_client = socket.socket()
my_socket_client.connect(("localhost", 6969))
bufsize = 1000
print("Send message")
# I changed it to raw_input(); input() does not for string input with python 2.7
message=raw_input()
# Are you trying to encode the message? To make it simple, skip it
data2 = bytes(message) # ,"utf-8")
#enviar los datos
my_socket_client.send(data2)
data_received= my_socket_client.recv(bufsize)
print (data_received)
```

Sample output from server side:

```
Waiting message...
('Message:', 'message from client')
Closing...
```

Sample output from client side:

```
Send message
message from client
Bye
```