# One-way communication in python

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stdin, communication

For the last day I've been trying to get some one-way continuous communication between two python scripts as an exercise for a bigger project. However, subprocess.communicate only allows a one-time message, and so far I haven't been able to get the second script to listen and print stdin data when written. I have looked extensively on stackoverflow but haven't found an answer that works yet (I just want to use subprocess, sys or os modules).

Specifically, I wish to write data to stdin periodically (say every second) and another python script to be listening continuously and when something is written to stdin to print the data.

The closest I have gotten is the following:

```
## script1.py (the script run)

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import time

inp1 = 'string1 /n'.encode()
inp2 = 'string2 /n'.encode()
inp3 = 'string3 /n'.encode()

p=Popen(["python","script2.py"], stdin=PIPE)

for i in [inp1, inp2, inp3]:
   p.stdin.write(i)
   p.stdin.flush()
   time.sleep(1)

p.stdin.close()


## script2.py

import sys

while True:
   try:
      for line in sys.stdin:
         print(line)
   except EOFError:
      pass
```

This worked once, but now is just outputting the data in one batch after it has all been written. I also don't know if this is just because it is on a Raspberry Pi 4.

Comment: I think I'd be better to use sockets, set the port and make sure the scripts only talk/listen to what they should talk/listen to. Instead of listening to everything on stdin

Comment: Try `export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`. Python has stupid details for stdio buffering.

Comment: Don't listen to Daviid. Communicating over stdio is a much better option than TCP sockets where possible. If you really don't want to use stdio use Unix sockets not TCP. They are supported on recent versions of Windows apparently.

Comment: Thanks @Timmmm, I executed PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 before running script1 but same result

Comment: If you're ever planning on having the scripts on different machines (PC and PI4) you will have to use TCP/IP sockets, if not, Unix Sockets are faster and lighter.

Comment: IP Sockets would allow for crossplatform communication too. So think about how that bigger project will work, you might not need IP sockets and crossplatform communication for this RBPI4 project but you could still learn it.

Comment: @Daviid Is any ethernet connection required? For the pi isn't connected to any

Comment: No, you could use WiFi or just localhost for internal communication

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36817549/how-to-connect-a-client-to-a-server-with-sockets-using-ip-adress-in-python

Comment: If networking is required at a later date it is trivial to switch from stdio to TCP at that point because they are both simple streams. If you don't need it now then YAGNI.

Comment: Try `Popen(..., bufsize=0)`?

Comment: Note you may want `string1\n`(`\n` is a newline, `/n` is just `"/n"`).

Comment: @AKX that was precisely the error, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
# script1.py
import subprocess
import sys
import time

inputs = [
    'string1',
    'string2',
    'string3',
]

p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "script2.py"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0)
for i in inputs:
    p.stdin.write(i.encode())
    p.stdin.write(b'\n')
    time.sleep(1)
```

```
# script2.py

import sys
import time

for line in sys.stdin:  # assumes utf-8 (or other encoding set by environment); use `sys.stdin.buffer` for binary
    print(time.time(), repr(line))
```

seems to work fine for me; I get (20 seconds ago or so, your timestamps will vary ;-) )

```
1696317616.977679 'string1\n'
1696317617.9684181 'string2\n'
1696317618.9715588 'string3\n'
```

If you're working with text only, you can simplify your life by setting `encoding` directly on `Popen` and let it handle encoding:

```
# script1.py
import subprocess
import sys
import time

inputs = [
    "string1",
    "string2",
    "string3",
]

p = subprocess.Popen(
    [sys.executable, "script2.py"],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    bufsize=0,
    encoding="utf-8",
)
for i in inputs:
    p.stdin.write(f"{i}\n")
    time.sleep(1)
```